# Simple simulation of the Law of Large Numbers - LLN in R?

Tags: r

I understand the Law of Large Numbers, but can't find any simple example simulating it in R.
Can someone give me an example of this law in R?

Regards!

Comment: Please consider reading up on [ask] and how to produce a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Currently, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question will likely be closed, but perhaps something like this will suffice:

```
die <- 1:6
roll <- function(n) {
  mean(sample(die, size = n, replace = TRUE))
}

plot(sapply(1:1000, roll), type = "l", xlab = "# of dice", ylab = "average")
abline(h = 3.5, col = "red")
```

[image: Plot]